# Why are Higher Order Functions hiding my ES6 Class properties?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

**EDIT:** I've added updated screenshots (at the end), for further clarification.

I'm attempting to use high order functions to compose subclasses/mixins but noticed **I can only access the properties of the very first class I extend** and can only access the properties of any subsequent classes *after* I've called the class. Here is a contrived example of what I mean:

These are functions that will apply subclasses to the parent class:

```
export const middleNameClass = middlename => BaseClass => {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    constructor(args) {
      super(args);
      this.middlename = middlename;
    }
  };
};

export const lastNameClass = lastname => BaseClass => {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    constructor(args) {
      super(args);
      this.lastname = lastname;
    }
  };
};
```

Here is `firstNameClass`, which will be extended directly by the parent class, `Person`:

```
class firstNameClass {
  constructor(args) {
    this.firstname = args;
  }
}
```

This is `Person`, which extends `firstNameClass`:

```
class Person extends firstNameClass {
  constructor(args) {
    super(args);
    this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this);

    // I'm using to log class properties to the console
    this.getNames();
  }

  getNames() {
    console.log("this inside getNames(): ", this);
    console.log("firstnames inside getNames(): ", this.firstname);
    console.log("middlenames inside getNames(): ", this.middlename);
    console.log("lastnames inside getNames(): ", this.lastname);
  }
}
```

and finally, here is where I apply my higher order functions and create my class:

```
const enhancedClass = compose(
  middleNameClass("Allan"),
  lastNameClass("Poe")
)(Person);

const namedPerson = new enhancedClass("Edgar");
```

However, I see the following when I check my console.log:

```
this.firstnames inside getNames(): Edgar
this.middlenames inside getNames(): undefined
this.lastnames inside getNames(): undefined
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here are the contents of my `Person` class:
[image]

and here is what is output to the console, after I create the class:
[image: the]

Comment: Where is `compose` defined?

Comment: @Paulpro I'm using `https://github.com/stoeffel/compose-function/blob/master/module/index.js` but the same thing happens with Lodash's `flowRight`

Answer (score 2):

At `new enhancedClass('Edgar')`, this happens:

- `lastNameClass`'s constructor calls `super`
- `middleNameClass`'s constructor calls `super`
- `Person`'s constructor calls `super`
- `firstNameClass` does `this.firstName = 'Edgar'`
- Return to `Person`, which calls `getNames`
- Return to `middleNameClass`, which does `this.middleName = 'Allan'`
- Return to `lastNameClass`, which does `this.lastName = 'Poe'`

Calling `getNames` afterwards should work. Same thing would've happened if you used `extend` every time.

Comment: This is the correct answer to another question. I only created `getNames` to demonstrate how certain properties are `undefined` when accessed within my target class; It's not the problem in itself.

Comment: @Wilhelm It says that they are undefined when you access them inside the `Person` constructor, where they are not yet initialised. They are only created in the `enhancedClass`, which does extend `Person`.

Comment: @Wilhelm Maybe what you actually wanted is to make `Person` the "target class" as you call it, and instead of subclassing it have `Person` itself extend the mixin classes:  `class Person extends middleNameClass("Allan")(lastNameClass("Poe")(firstNameClass)) { … }`

Comment: @Bergi That approach could definitely work but I would sacrifice readability, as currying makes it convoluted and difficult to follow. It seems like I may have to do something to the `prototype` inside each of my functions.

Comment: @Wilhelm Of course you can also use `compose` or functions with multiple parameters or whatever syntax you like, but the idea of having the mixins that `Person` wants to use in the `extends` clause is important.

Comment: @Bergi [mixwith.js](https://github.com/justinfagnani/mixwith.js) comes the closest to what you suggestion but there's still the issue of composition. Honestly, I may just use a plain old `Object`s and scrap the idea of "Higher Order Classes," as this seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question but maybe it's a solution to your problem

JavaScript doesn't have multiple inheritance but luckily for you functional programming has nothing to do JavaScript's class system, object prototypes, or other object-oriented concepts. Functional programming is *all* about functions!

We begin writing our inheritable modules with some functions

```
// module 1
const hasFirstName = (firstName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'firstName', firstName)
}

// module 2
const hasMiddleName = (middleName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'middleName', middleName)
}
  
// module 3
const hasLastName = (lastName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'lastName', lastName)
}
```

We haven't defined `field` yet, but don't worry. Let's look at a somewhat more involved module next

```
// module 4
const nameable = (first, middle, last) => o =>
{
  inherit (o, hasFirstName (first))
  inherit (o, hasMiddleName (middle))
  inherit (o, hasLastName (last))
  method (o, 'getFullName', (self) => `${self.firstName} ${self.middleName} ${self.lastName}`)
  method (o, 'sayHelloTo', (self, other) => `Hello ${other.getFullName ()}, my name is ${self.getFullName ()}`)
}
```

OK, so now we can see how some modules can be composed of other modules. Before we look at `inherit` and `method`, let's see how we'd use our module

```
const Person = (first, middle, last) =>
  Obj (self => {
    inherit (self, nameable (first, middle, last))
  })
```

So maybe you're annoyed that I keep making stuff up in each new code paste, but this is a very powerful practice called [*wishful thinking*](http://wiki.c2.com/?WishfulThinking)

> "Wishful Thinking" is a very powerful programming practice:
>
> Before implementing a component you write some of the code that *actually uses* it. This way you discover what functions with what parameters you really need, which leads to a very good interface. You will also have some good test code for your component.
>
> The idea is based on the fact that an interface's purpose is to simplify the code that uses the component, not to simplify the code that *implements* it.

Exercising this practice, we wished up this imaginary object system based on what we need it to do - *not* based on what JavaScript's object system is capable of.

Of course we expect that using our `Person` will be straightforward

```
const p1 =
  Person ('Augusta', 'Ada', 'King-Noel', 166)

const p2 =
  Person ('Gerald', 'Jay', 'Sussman', 71)

console.log (p1.sayHelloTo (p2))
// Hello Gerald Jay Sussman, my name is Augusta Ada King-Noel
```

And here's the dependencies: What I want you to see here is that no `class` or even `this` is used. So even if JavaScript didn't have a native object system, this demonstrates you could make your own

```
const Obj = (f, instance = {}) =>
  (f (instance), instance)
  
const inherit = (o, f) =>
  Object.assign (o, f (o))

const field = (o, name, value) =>
  Object.assign (o, { [name]: value })

const method = (o, name, f) =>
  Object.assign (o, { [name]: (...xs) => f (o, ...xs) })
```

Full program demonstration

```js
// DIY class system
const Obj = (f, instance = {}) =>
  (f (instance), instance)
  
const inherit = (o, f) =>
  Object.assign (o, f (o))

const field = (o, name, value) =>
  Object.assign (o, { [name]: value })

const method = (o, name, f) =>
  Object.assign (o, { [name]: (...xs) => f (o, ...xs) })

// module 1
const hasFirstName = (firstName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'firstName', firstName)
}

// module 2
const hasMiddleName = (middleName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'middleName', middleName)
}
  
// module 3
const hasLastName = (lastName = "") => o =>
{
  field (o, 'lastName', lastName)
}

// module 4
const nameable = (first, middle, last) => o =>
{
  inherit (o, hasFirstName (first))
  inherit (o, hasMiddleName (middle))
  inherit (o, hasLastName (last))
  method (o, 'getFullName', (self) => `${self.firstName} ${self.middleName} ${self.lastName}`)
  method (o, 'sayHelloTo', (self, other) => `Hello ${other.getFullName ()}, my name is ${self.getFullName ()}`)
}

// Person class
const Person = (first, middle, last) =>
  Obj (self => {
    inherit (self, nameable (first, middle, last))
  })

// demo
const p1 =
  Person ('Augusta', 'Ada', 'King-Noel')

const p2 =
  Person ('Gerald', 'Jay', 'Sussman')

console.log (p1.sayHelloTo (p2))
// Hello Gerald Jay Sussman, my name is Augusta Ada King-Noel
```

Our Person class can obviously define its own fields and methods as well

```
const dateDiff = (d1, d2) =>
  Math.abs (d1 - d2) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 >> 0

const Person = (first, middle, last, birthdate = new Date) =>
  Obj (self => {
    inherit (self, nameable (first, middle, last))
    field (self, 'birthdate', birthdate)
    method (self, 'calculateAge', (self) => dateDiff (new Date, self.birthdate))
    method (self, 'sayAge', (self) => `I am ${self.calculateAge()} years old`)
  })

const p2 =
  Person ('Gerald', 'Jay', 'Sussman', new Date ('February 8, 1947'))

console.log (p2.sayAge ())
// I am 71 years old
```

Get creative and invent any other features you want

- Maybe you want to make an `overrideMethod` that gives you the ability to define a new method with the same name, but still give the caller access to both methods
- Maybe you want `privateMethod` or `classMethod` helpers
- Maybe `field` could be enhanced to emit events when values changed
- Maybe `field` could be changed so that values cannot be set, where `mutableField` could be used for fields that can change

Write it how you want it then make your wishes come true. Any limitations are you own.

Comment: I don't understand JS much, but "wishful thinking" is something I was thinking about recently quite a lot. Maybe one day we'll just write stuff down without at all implementing the helpers we used! (when there can be only one valid implementation). or e.g. we write yet another piece of code and get warned "no, that's inconsistent! would be impossible to implement!".

Comment: Now the real question is: would *that* language be high-level *enough*? :D