# Functional "real-time" composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, state

I recently came across a [great article](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6) covering the benefits of object composition VS traditional inheritance.

Hopefully my question is not going to be flagged as opinionated but I'd like to know a good approach to using composition for when an object changes based on a user's game interaction.

Using the articles code as an example:

```
const canCast = (state) => ({
    cast: (spell) => {
        console.log(`${state.name} casts ${spell}!`);
        state.mana--;
    }
})

const canFight = (state) => ({
    fight: () => {
        console.log(`${state.name} slashes at the foe!`);
        state.stamina--;
    }
})

const fighter = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    stamina: 100
  }

  return Object.assign(state, canFight(state));
}

const mage = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    mana: 100
  }

  return Object.assign(state, canCast(state));
}

scorcher = mage('Scorcher')
scorcher.cast('fireball');    // Scorcher casts fireball!
console.log(scorcher.mana)    // 99

slasher = fighter('Slasher')
slasher.fight();              // Slasher slashes at the foe!
console.log(slasher.stamina)  // 99
```

How do I use composition to change the state of the Character object during run-time? Instead of the Mage object already existing I want the Character object to change based on a game event eg. Character picks up a staff and now becomes a "Mage" who can now Cast spells. First thing that comes to mind is to have a state property in Character that changes based on the interaction and the Character somehow "inherits" the ability to now Cast and gains a mana state property.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603756/633183) help you? Otherwise I'd be happy to offer my opinionated answer :D

Comment: That's a terrible article, and they get object composition completely, entirely wrong. That's just inheritance done manually. https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6q2lk0/why_composition_is_harder_with_classes/dku34cl/

Comment: @JeffM where can I read up then? Or do you perhaps know another "non-OO" way of handling my question? Or should I just use OO inheritance in this regard? The deeper I go down this rabbit whole it becomes REALLY difficult to do things "the right way" as it all seems to opinionated...

I'm feeling like OO SOLID is easier to stick to and bin the idea of FP.

Comment: Here's some object composition reading material across a variety of languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a - https://web.archive.org/web/20170707220607/https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696786/1698612

Comment: Also I'd re-think why you're searching for a non-OO answer. You seem to think an OO solution won't let you add states/properties during runtime, but it can, and that's what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) solves situations exactly like this.

```
class Character {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = 100;
    this.items = [];
  }
}

const fighterDecorator = character => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf({
    character,
    stamina: 100,
    fight() {
      console.log(`${this.name} slashes at the foe!`);
      this.stamina--;
    }
  }, character);
}

const mageDecorator = character => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf({
    character,
    mana: 100,
    cast(spell) {
      console.log(`${this.name} casts ${spell}!`);
      this.mana--;      
    }
  }, character);
}

let character = new Character("Bob");

// Can't fight; can't cast
// character.fight(); // TypeError: not a function
// character.cast(); // TypeError: not a function

// Character becomes a fighter at runtime
// Equiping an item and decorating new behavior are separate statements
character.items.push("sword");
character = fighterDecorator(character);
character.fight();              // Bob slashes at the foe!
console.log(character.stamina)  // 99
console.log(character.items)    // ["sword"]

// Character becomes normal unit again
// Remove decoration and remove item
character = character.character;
character.items = character.items.filter(item => item !== "sword");

// Once again, can't fight, can't cast
// character.fight(); // TypeError: not a function
// character.cast(); // TypeError: not a function

// Character becomes a mage at runtime
// Equiping an item and decorating new behavior are separate statements
character.items.push("staff");
character = mageDecorator(character);
character.cast("fireball");  // Bob casts fireball!
console.log(character.mana)  // 99
console.log(character.items) // ["staff"]
```

Comment: I like this but can't quite understand how equipping an item would change your fighter type? Does your example not mean that I have to create the unit as its specified class and not during "play-time"?

Comment: Equipping an item and decorating behavior would happen in separate statements. I updated my posted code to show that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question properly, its better to have one functional object composition which has multiple methods, like below . Here you can create individual objects which can have either have one or all the functionalities defined in the below main object . Basically, `can` here is function which provides set of operation methods and can be used while creating your objects at run time. well I have give some example below . hopefully this helps

**note even this is opinionated**

```
const can = (state) => {
 return {
    canFight : (spell) => {
      console.log(`${state.name} slashes at the foe!`);
        state.stamina--;
    },
   cast: (spell) => {
        console.log(`${state.name} casts ${spell}!`);
        state.mana--;
   }
 }
}
```

---

Usages

```
const fighter = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    stamina: 100
  }

  return Object.assign(state, can(state));
}

const mage = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    mana: 100
  }

  return Object.assign(state, can(state));
}

const soldier = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    stamina: 100
  }

  return Object.assign(state, {fight: can(state).canFight(name)});
}
```

Comment: This kinda helps but not exactly. If a character is created I don't want to assign his type (mage, fighter, soldier) at creation. When one of his properties changes eg. picks up a wand, he then becomes a mage. If the same character drops the wand and picks up the sword he is now a fighter etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem it's better to use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) instead of object composition. Duck typing makes use of the [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) to ensure type safety:

> If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably *is* a duck.

For this problem, we'll make use of an analogous "mage test" and "fighter test" respectively:

1. If it has mana and is holding a staff then it is a mage.
2. If it has stamina and is holding a sword then it is a fighter.

Note that we can still use object composition to keep our code modular. We'll create prototypes for `character`, `fighter` and `mage` and then compose them together to get the final prototype:

```js
const character = {
    health: 100,
    right: null,
    left: null,
    equip(item) {
        const {name, right, left} = this;
             if (right === null) this.right = item;
        else if (left  === null) this.left  = item;
        else console.error(`${name} is already holding ${right} and ${left}.`);
    }
};
```

First, we have the prototype for characters. Every character has at least four properties: `name`, `health`, `right` (i.e. the item equipped in the right hand) and `left` (i.e. the item equipped in the left hand). We provide default values for `health`, `right` and `left`. However, we don't provide any default value for `name`. Hence, when we create a new character we must provide it a name.

```js
const fighter = {
    stamina: 100,
    fight(foe) {
        const {name, stamina, right, left} = this;
        if (right !== "a sword" && left !== "a sword")
            console.error(`${name} is not holding a sword.`);
        else if (stamina === 0) console.error(`${name} has no stamina.`);
        else { this.stamina--; console.log(`${name} slashes at ${foe}.`); }
    }
};
```

Then, we have the prototype for fighters. Note that since a fighter is also a character, we can use the `name`, `right` and `left` properties in the `fight` method. In addition, fighters have a `stamina` property which has a default value of 100.

```js
const mage = {
    mana: 100,
    cast(spell) {
        const {name, mana, right, left} = this;
        if (right !== "a staff" && left !== "a staff")
            console.error(`${name} is not holding a staff.`);
        else if (mana === 0) console.error(`${name} has no mana.`);
        else { this.mana--; console.log(`${name} casts ${spell}.`); }
    }
};
```

Next, we have the prototype for mages. Like fighters, mages are also characters and hence they too can make use of character-specific properties. In addition, mages have a `mana` property with a default value of 100.

```js
Object.assign(character, fighter, mage);

Object.prototype.create = function (properties) {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(this), properties);
};

const gandalf = character.create({ name: "Gandalf" });

gandalf.equip("a sword");
gandalf.equip("a staff");

gandalf.fight("the goblin");
gandalf.cast("a blinding light");
```

Finally, we use `Object.assign` to compose all the prototypes together by extending the `character` prototype with the `fighter` and `mage` prototypes. We also extend `Object.prototype` with a useful `create` function to easily create instances of prototypes. We use this method to create an instance of `character` named Gandalf and we make him fight a goblin.

```js
const mage = {
    mana: 100,
    cast(spell) {
        const {name, mana, right, left} = this;
        if (right !== "a staff" && left !== "a staff")
            console.error(`${name} is not holding a staff.`);
        else if (mana === 0) console.error(`${name} has no mana.`);
        else { this.mana--; console.log(`${name} casts ${spell}.`); }
    }
};

const fighter = {
    stamina: 100,
    fight(foe) {
        const {name, stamina, right, left} = this;
        if (right !== "a sword" && left !== "a sword")
            console.error(`${name} is not holding a sword.`);
        else if (stamina === 0) console.error(`${name} has no stamina.`);
        else { this.stamina--; console.log(`${name} slashes at ${foe}.`); }
    }
};

const character = {
    health: 100,
    right: null,
    left: null,
    equip(item) {
        const {name, right, left} = this;
             if (right === null) this.right = item;
        else if (left  === null) this.left  = item;
        else console.error(`${name} is already holding ${right} and ${left}.`);
    }
};

Object.assign(character, fighter, mage);

Object.prototype.create = function (properties) {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(this), properties);
};

const gandalf = character.create({ name: "Gandalf" });

gandalf.equip("a sword");
gandalf.equip("a staff");

gandalf.fight("the goblin");
gandalf.cast("a blinding light");
```

Above is the demo of the entire script put together, demonstrating how it works. As you can see, you can break up your character prototype into several different prototypes such as `mage` and `fighter` and then put them all back together using `Object.assign`. This makes adding new character types much easier and much more manageable. Duck typing is used to ensure that a fighter (a character equipped with a sword) can't cast a spell, etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: I get where you're coming from and a while back I would have considered taking this approach. Now though, I don't think a "Person" should be all types of fighters as this class would get massive and even using composition your Object.assign() would be overkill. Imagine if you had 20 different "fighters"? This class would just continue expanding?

Comment: If having a massive class is your only concern, I've updated my answer showing how to break up the class into smaller prototypes and them recombine them into a single prototype. This is possible due to the prototype-class isomorphism as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640910/783743).