# Mixin and Trait based Compostion in JS

Tags: javascript, class, traits, mixins, composition

I got some trouble with **compostions** and **mixin**.
For examples, lets imagine that we have a `AHero` and `Hero1` object.
All heroes can move, so `AHero.move()` is a thing.
And now, at a moment of the dev, I want to add the possibility to `stun` and `beStunned`. So I make a new object that look like this ( called `stunTrait`)  :

```
{
  stunned : false,
  stun(),
  beStun,
}
```

And I decide to give to possibility to heroes to `stun` and `beStunned`. So I do a mixin :

```
class AHero extends stunTrait(superclass).
```

Now I want that a stunned hero can not move.
So in `Ahero` :

```
move() {
  if (this.stunned) return;
  ...
}
```

Later I find out `stun` was a bad idea, so I decide to stop implementing the `stunTrait`. And now I must find all stunned things  in my `Ahero` class, and this can be sometimes hard, and even harder if child class did some other things with this stun stuff.

Is there a way to avoid that ? A better design ?

---

```
class Object{
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class AHero extends stunTrait(Object) {
  constructor(x, y, moveSpeed) {
    this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
  }

  move() {
    super.move();
    this.speed = moveSpeed;
  }
}

class hero1 extends AHero {
  constructor(x, y, moveSpeed) {}
}

let stunTrait = function(object) {
  return class extends object {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);

      this.stunned = false;
    }

    move() {
      if (this.stunned) this.speed = 0;
    }
  }
}

let hero = new hero1(40, 50, 100);
hero.stunned = true;
hero.move();

// This work, bcs AHero.move() is called before stunTrait.move()
// but if for some reason, I decide that only hero1 should have stunTrait
// So : class hero1 extends stunTrait(AHero)
// stunTrait.move() will be called after, so stunned will not be applied
// How make compostion without breaking inheritance ?
```

Comment: Example added. Thanks for you attentions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's given design decision targets the modification of the `move` behavior that already has been implemented from the `class` side.

Thus a `stun` behavior is not only responsible for implementing its `stun` specific state handling, it also has to *decide* whether and/or how to change a `move` behavior's control flow.

For this it relies on existing implementations not only of `move` but also on `setSpeed`.

The concept of mixins really does not fit with the OP's approach for it just mixes additional behavior into other objects. But the given special case has to handle the naming conflict of `move` too. And that's something what traits are for.

If, in JavaScript, there once was a real support for `applicable types` which have to be capable of both kinds of composition trait- and object-composition, as well as of method modification, a possible solution might look similar to the next provided one.

```js
const withStunBehavior = Trait.create(function (use, applicator) {

  function moveInterceptor(proceedMove, interceptor, argsArray) {
  //console.log("withStunBehavior::moveInterceptor - this.isStunned() : ", this.isStunned());
    if (this.isStunned()) {

      this.setSpeed(0);
    }/* else {
      return proceedMove.call(this);
    }*/
    return proceedMove.call(this);
  }

  applicator(function (isStunnedValue) {
    isStunnedValue = !!isStunnedValue;
  //console.log("withStunBehavior::applicator - isStunnedValue : ", isStunnedValue);

    this.beStun = function beStun () {
      isStunnedValue = true;
    };
    this.unban = function unban () {
      isStunnedValue = false;
    };
    this.isStunned = function isStunned () {
      return isStunnedValue;
    };

  }).requires([

    "setSpeed",
    "move"

  ]).around(

    "move", moveInterceptor
  );
});


class AHero {
  constructor(stateValue) {
    var
      aHero = this;

    aHero.getSpeed = function getSpeed () {
      return stateValue.moveSpeed;
    };
    aHero.setSpeed = function setSpeed (speedValue) {
      return (stateValue.moveSpeed = speedValue);
    };

    // withStunBehavior.call(aHero);
  }
  move() {
    var
      speedValue = this.getSpeed();

    if (speedValue === 0) {
      console.log("Hero does not move at all. Its speed is " + speedValue + ".");
    } else {
      console.log("Hero moves with speed " + speedValue + ".");
    }
    return speedValue;
  }
}


class AHeroWithStunBehavior extends AHero {

  constructor(stateValue) {
    super(stateValue);

    withStunBehavior.call(this);
  }
}


var
  hero = new AHero({ x: 0, y: 0, moveSpeed: 200 });

console.log("\n");
console.log("hero.getSpeed() : ", hero.getSpeed());
console.log("hero.move() : ", hero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("hero.setSpeed(0) : ", hero.setSpeed(0));
console.log("hero.getSpeed() : ", hero.getSpeed());
console.log("hero.move() : ", hero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("hero.setSpeed(100) : ", hero.setSpeed(100));
console.log("hero.getSpeed() : ", hero.getSpeed());
console.log("hero.move() : ", hero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("hero.isStunned : ", hero.isStunned);
console.log("hero.beStun : ", hero.beStun);
console.log("hero.unban : ", hero.unban);

var
  stunningHero = new AHeroWithStunBehavior({ x: 40, y: 50, moveSpeed: 130 });

console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.isStunned : ", stunningHero.isStunned);
console.log("stunningHero.beStun : ", stunningHero.beStun);
console.log("stunningHero.unban : ", stunningHero.unban);
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.getSpeed() : ", stunningHero.getSpeed());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.setSpeed(0) : ", stunningHero.setSpeed(0));
console.log("stunningHero.getSpeed() : ", stunningHero.getSpeed());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.setSpeed(90) : ", stunningHero.setSpeed(90));
console.log("stunningHero.getSpeed() : ", stunningHero.getSpeed());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.beStun() : ", stunningHero.beStun());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.setSpeed(160) : ", stunningHero.setSpeed(160));
console.log("stunningHero.getSpeed() : ", stunningHero.getSpeed());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.unban() : ", stunningHero.unban());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
console.log("\n");
console.log("stunningHero.setSpeed(160) : ", stunningHero.setSpeed(160));
console.log("stunningHero.getSpeed() : ", stunningHero.getSpeed());
console.log("stunningHero.move() : ", stunningHero.move());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>(function(r){function g(a){var c="none",b;Y(a)&&(ta(a)?c=ua:(b=Z(a),t("^class\\s+"+a.name+"\\s+\\{").test(b)?c=va:t("\\([^)]*\\)\\s+=>\\s+\\(").test(b)?c=wa:z(a)&&(c=xa(a)?ya:za(a)||Aa(a)||Ba(a)?Ca:aa)));return c===aa}function C(a){return["^\\[object\\s+",a,"\\]$"].join("")}function v(a,c){var b=Da[c];return!!b&&0<=b.indexOf(a)}function M(a,c,b){return function(){var d=arguments;c.apply(b,d);return a.apply(b,d)}}function N(a,c,b){return function(){var d=arguments,e=a.apply(b,d);c.apply(b,d);return e}}function Ea(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments;c.call(b,e,d);return a.apply(b,e)}}function Fa(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f=a.apply(b,e);c.call(b,e,d);return f}}function Ga(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f=a.apply(b,e);c.call(b,f,e,d);return f}}function Ha(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f;try{f=a.apply(b,e)}catch(l){c.call(b,l,e,d)}return f}}function Ia(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f,g;try{f=a.apply(b,e)}catch(m){g=m}c.call(b,g||f,e,d);return f}}function Ja(a,c,b,d){return function(){return c.call(b,a,c,arguments,d)}}function Ka(a,c){return function(){var b=this[a];g(b)||(b=u);this[a]=M(b,c,this)}}function La(a,c){return function(){var b=this[a];g(b)||(b=u);this[a]=N(b,c,this)}}function Ma(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ea(d,c,this,b)}}function Na(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Fa(d,c,this,b)}}function Oa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ga(d,c,this,b)}}function Pa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ha(d,c,this,b)}}function Qa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ia(d,c,this,b)}}function Ra(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ja(d,c,this,b)}}function ba(a,c,b){a.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"without",traitList:c,methodNameList:b}))}function ca(a,c,b,d){a.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"as",trait:c,methodName:b,methodAlias:d}))}function da(a){return ea(p(a)).reduce(function(a,b){q(b)&&a.push(F(b));return a},[])}function fa(){var a,c,b,d,e;if(O(this))if(d=this.valueOf(),e=d.parentLink,w(e))if(b=e.getSetup(),a=b.chainData,c=a.recentCalleeName,v(c,"without"))if(c=da(arguments),1<=c.length)a.recentCalleeName="without",ba(b,d.traitList,c);else throw new h("Not even a single <String> type was passed to 'without' as to be excluded method name.");else{a=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",c,"().without()'"].join("");if("applyBehavior"==c)throw new n([a," in case of excluding one or more certain behaviors."].join(""));throw new n(a);}else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return e}function P(a,c){var b=a.getSetup();if(Sa(c,a.valueOf().traitList))b.chainData.recentCalleeName="applyTraits",b=new Q({traitList:c,parentLink:a}),a.putChild(b);else throw new h("Any trait that got passed to 'apply' needs to be registered before via 'use'.");return b}function Sa(a,c){return a.every(function(a){return 0<=c.indexOf(a)})}function Ta(){var a;a=this.getSetup();var c=this.valueOf().traitList;I(this,a,a.chainData.recentCalleeName);a=P(this,c);return fa.apply(a,arguments)}function Ua(){var a=this.getSetup(),c=this.valueOf().traitList;I(this,a,a.chainData.recentCalleeName);return P(this,c)}function ga(){var a,c,b;b=p(arguments);if(w(this))if(a=this.getSetup(),c=a.chainData,c=c.recentCalleeName,I(this,a,c),a=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",c,"().apply()'"].join(""),v(c,"apply"))if(x(b[0]))if(q(b[1]))if(v(c,"applyBehavior")){c=b[0];b=F(b[1]);a=this.getSetup();var d;if(0<=this.valueOf().traitList.indexOf(c))if(d={},c.call(d),g(d[b]))a.chainData.recentCalleeName="applyBehavior",b=new R({trait:c,methodName:b,parentLink:this}),this.putChild(b);else throw new k(["The requested '",b,"' method has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'apply'."].join(""));else throw new h("Any trait that got passed to 'apply' needs to be registered before via 'use'.");}else throw new n([a," in case of applying just a certain behavior."].join(""));else if(p(b).every(x))if(v(c,"applyTraits"))b=P(this,b);else throw new n([a," in case of applying from one or more traits."].join(""));else throw new h("'apply(\u2026)' excepts either, as its 2nd delimiting argument, just a 'String' type or exclusively one or more 'Trait' and 'Function' types.");else throw new h("'apply(<Trait|Function>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(a);else throw new k("'use(\u2026).apply(\u2026)' only works within a validly chained context, please do not try spoofing the latter.");return b}function ha(){var a;a=this;if(O(a)||G(a))a=a.valueOf(),a=a.parentLink,a=ga.apply(a,arguments);else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return a}function I(a,c,b){var d,e;a&&!c.chainData.isTerminated&&(d=a.getChild())&&(e=d.valueOf())&&("applyTraits"==b&&O(d)?ba(c,e.traitList,[]):"applyBehavior"==b&&G(d)&&(a=e.methodName,ca(c,e.trait,a,a)));c.chainData.recentCalleeName="apply"}function R(a){this.valueOf=function(){return{trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName,parentLink:a.parentLink}};this.toString=function(){return["ApplyLink::singleBehavior :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};return this}function G(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof R||g(a.as)&&g(a.after)&&g(a.before)&&g(a.valueOf)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&x(c.trait)&&q(c.methodName)&&w(c.parentLink))}function Q(a){this.valueOf=function(){return{traitList:a.traitList,parentLink:a.parentLink}};this.toString=function(){return["ApplyLink::fromTraits :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};return this}function O(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof Q||g(a.without)&&g(a.valueOf)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&T(c.traitList)&&w(c.parentLink))}function U(a,c){var b=null;this.getSetup=function(){return c};this.deleteChild=function(){b=null};this.putChild=function(a){b=a};this.getChild=function(){return b};this.valueOf=function(){return{traitList:p(a.traitList)}};this.toString=function(){return["UseRoot :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};this.apply=ga.bind(this);this.apply.all=Ua.bind(this);this.apply.all.without=Ta.bind(this);return this}function w(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof U||g(a.apply)&&g(a.valueOf)&&g(a.getSetup)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&T(c.traitList)&&(c=a.getSetup())&&ia(c))}function Va(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ka(a,c));else throw new h("'before(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'before(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Wa(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ma(a,c));else throw new h("'before.stateful(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'before.stateful(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Xa(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(La(a,c));else throw new h("'after(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'after(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Ya(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Na(a,c));else throw new h("'after.stateful(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'after.stateful(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Za(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Oa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterReturning(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterReturning(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function $a(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Pa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterThrowing(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterThrowing(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function ab(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Qa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterFinally(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterFinally(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function bb(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ra(a,c));else throw new h("'around(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'around(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function cb(){var a=this.applicator,c=a.root,b=a.didRequire;if(a.canRequire)if(a.canRequire=!1,a.didRequire=!0,b=da(arguments),1<=b.length)a.requires=b;else throw new h("Not even a single <String> type was passed to 'requires' as method name that a trait, at its apply time, expects to be present at least.");else{if(b)throw new n("'requires' can be invoked exactly once, right after having executed a trait's 'applicator' method.");throw new n("'requires' can not bee invoked after a modifier method, but has to be the direct follower of a trait's 'applicator' method.");}return c}function db(a){I(this.useTraits.root,this,this.chainData.recentCalleeName);this.chainData.isTerminated=!0;var c=this.applicator,b=this.useTraits.rules,d=0>=b.length;if(!d&&!ja(b))throw new k("The trait composition language's rule set does not result in applicable behavior. This happens e.g. if all behavior has been deleted via 'without'.");if(null!=a)if(g(a=F(a)))c.body=a,a.call(c.proxy);else throw new h("The applicator should either stay empty or receive a sole applicable type like a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else d&&0>=c.modifiers.length&&D.warn("The trait descriptor till now did neither receive an applicable function via the 'applicator' method nor any composition rule via 'use(\u2026).apply(\u2026)' nor any method modifier.");return c.root}function eb(){var a;a=ea(p(arguments)).filter(function(a){return x(a)});if(1<=a.length)a=new U({traitList:a},this);else throw new h("Not even a single valid 'Trait' or 'Function' type has been provided to 'use(<Trait|Function>[, \u2026])'.");return this.useTraits.root=a}function y(a,c){return a.findIndex(function(a){return a.trait===c})}function ka(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName}}function la(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,fromTrait:a.fromTrait,methodName:a.methodName}}function A(a){this.valueOf=function(){return fb[a.type](a)}}function ja(a){var c=!0;if(1<=a.length){var b={},c=ma(a),d=na(c);d.forEach(function(a){a.trait.call(a.proxy)});a.forEach(function(a){a.execute(b,d)});c=1<=J(b).length}return c}function gb(a,c,b){var d;if(b[0]!==oa&&(d=c.reduce(function(b,c){g(a[c])||b.push(c);return b},[]),1<=d.length))throw new h("The type misses following required method(s) \u2026 '"+d.join("', '")+"'.");return d}function hb(a,c,b){a.forEach(function(a){a.call(c,b)})}function ib(a){this.call=function(){var c=p(arguments),b;b=c.shift();b=null!=b&&b||null;a.apply(b,c);return b};this.apply=function(c,b){null==b&&(b=[]);c=null!=c&&c||null;a.apply(c,b);return c};return this}function jb(a){this.requires=function(){return p(a)};return this}function kb(a){var c=[],b={};a.call(b,oa);c=J(b).sort(function(a,b){return a<b&&-1||a>b&&1||0});b=null;this.keys=function(){return p(c)};return this}function pa(a,c){this.toString=function(){return"[object Trait]"};this.valueOf=function(){return a};ib.call(this,a);jb.call(this,c);kb.call(this,a);return this}function qa(a){var c;if(c=!!a)(c=a instanceof pa)||(c="object"==typeof a&&g(a.call)&&g(a.apply)&&g(a.valueOf)&&g(a.valueOf()));return c}function x(a){return qa(a)||g(a)}function ma(a){return a.reduce(function(a,b){var c=b.valueOf(),e=c.trait,f=c.fromTrait;e&&0>a.indexOf(e)&&a.push(e);f&&0>a.indexOf(f)&&a.push(f);(c.traitList||[]).forEach(function(b){0>a.indexOf(b)&&a.push(b)});return a},[])}function na(a){return a.map(function(a){return{trait:a,proxy:{}}})}function lb(a,c,b,d){var e=[],f={};if(!(0>=c.length||ja(c)))throw new k("The trait composition language's rule set does not result in applicable behavior. This happens e.g. if all behavior has been deleted via 'without'.");g(b)&&(b.call(f),e=J(f));return[a,c,e,d].some(function(a){return 1<=a.length})}function mb(a){var c,b=a.useTraits.rules,d=a.applicator;a=d.body;var e=d.requires,d=d.modifiers,f=ma(b);lb(f,b,a,d)&&(d=function(a,b,c,d,e){return function(){var f=this,h=p(arguments),l=na(a);l.forEach(function(a){a.trait.apply(a.proxy,h)});b.forEach(function(a){a.execute(f,l)});gb(f,c,h);g(d)&&d.apply(f,h);hb(e,f,h);return f}}(f,b,e,a,d),c=new pa(d,e));return c}var V=r.Function,H=r.Object,B=r.Array,t=r.RegExp,S=r.JSON,h=r.TypeError,k=r.ReferenceError,n=r.SyntaxError,nb=V.prototype,K=H.prototype,ra=U.prototype,sa=Q.prototype,L=R.prototype,oa={},aa="applicable-function",ya="buildin-constructor",va="class-constructor",wa="arrow-function",ua="generator-function",Ca="interface-type",Da={without:["apply","applyTraits"],as:["apply","applyBehavior"],after:["apply","applyBehavior","after","before"],before:["apply","applyBehavior","after","before"],apply:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" "),applyTraits:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" "),applyBehavior:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" ")},fb={beforeWrap:ka,afterWrap:ka,beforeApply:la,afterApply:la,without:function(a){return{type:a.type,traitList:p(a.traitList),methodNameList:p(a.methodNameList)}},as:function(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName,methodAlias:a.methodAlias}}},ob={beforeWrap:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=b[d];a=a.methodName;c[a]=M((b&&b.proxy||{})[a],c[a],c)},afterWrap:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=b[d];a=a.methodName;c[a]=N((b&&b.proxy||{})[a],c[a],c)},beforeApply:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait),e=y(b,a.fromTrait),d=b[d],e=b[e];b=d&&d.proxy||{};e=e&&e.proxy||{};a=a.methodName;a in c&&delete c.methodName;c[a]=M(b[a],e[a],c)},afterApply:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait),e=y(b,a.fromTrait),d=b[d],e=b[e];b=d&&d.proxy||{};e=e&&e.proxy||{};a=a.methodName;a in c&&delete c.methodName;c[a]=N(b[a],e[a],c)},without:function(a,c,b){var d=a.traitList,e=a.methodNameList.reduce(function(a,b){a[b]=null;return a},{});d.forEach(function(a){a=y(b,a);var d=(a=b[a])&&a.proxy||{};J(d).forEach(function(a){a in e||(a in c&&delete c.methodName,c[a]=function(a,b){return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}(d[a],c))})});a=b=d=e=null},as:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=(b=b[d])&&b.proxy||{};d=a.methodAlias;a=a.methodName;d in c&&delete c.methodAlias;c[d]=function(a,b){return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}(b[a],c);a=b=d=b=b=d=a=null}},F=function(a,c){return function(b){return b==c?b:a.call(b).valueOf()}}(K.valueOf,null),E=function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(K.toString),Z=function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(nb.toString),pb=function(a){try{a.call(null,"length"),a=function(a,b){return function(c,e){return c!=b&&a.call(c,e)}}(a,null)}catch(c){a=function(a,c){return function(b,d){var e=b!=c;if(e)try{e=a.call(b,d)}catch(m){e=!0}return e}}(a,null)}return a}(K.propertyIsEnumerable),Y=function(a){return function(c){return typeof c==a}}(typeof V),z=function(a){return function(c){return Y(c)&&typeof c.call==a&&typeof c.apply==a}}(typeof V),qb=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Function")),ia=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Object")),rb=z(H.getPrototypeOf)&&H.getPrototypeOf||function(a){var c=a&&a.__proto__;return c||null===c?c:qb(a.constructor)?a.constructor.prototype:a instanceof H?K:null},W=function(a){return function(c){return(c=t(a).exec(Z(c)))&&c[1]}}("^function\\s+([^(]+)\\("),xa=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(W(c))}}("^(?:Array|ArrayBuffer|AsyncFunction|Atomics|Boolean|DataView|Date|Error|EvalError|Float32Array|Float64Array|Function|Generator|GeneratorFunction|Int16Array|Int32Array|Int8Array|InternalError|Collator|DateTimeFormat|NumberFormat|Iterator|Map|Number|Object|Promise|Proxy|RangeError|ReferenceError|RegExp|Bool16x8|Bool32x4|Bool64x2|Bool8x16|Float32x4|Float64x2|Int16x8|Int32x4|Int8x16|Uint16x8|Uint32x4|Uint8x16|Set|SharedArrayBuffer|StopIteration|String|Symbol|SyntaxError|TypeError|TypedArray|URIError|Uint16Array|Uint32Array|Uint8Array|Uint8ClampedArray|WeakMap|WeakSet)$"),X=function(a,c){var b=t(c);return b.test(W(a))||b.test(W(rb(a)))},za=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:Node|CharacterData|Event|DOMError|DOMException|DOMImplementation|DOMStringList|DOMTokenList|EventTarget|HTMLCollection|MutationObserver|MutationRecord|NodeFilter|NodeIterator|NodeList|Range|TreeWalker|URL|Document)$"),Aa=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:HTMLElement|HTMLMediaElement|Element)$"),Ba=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:CanvasRenderingContext2D|CanvasGradient|CanvasPattern|TextMetrics|ImageData|DOMStringMap|MediaError|HTMLCollection|NodeList)$"),ta=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("GeneratorFunction")),q=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("String")),T=z(B.isArray)&&B.isArray||function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Array")),sb=z(B.isArguments)&&B.isArguments||function(a,c){var b=function(b){return t(a).test(E(b))};b(arguments)||(b=function(a){return ia(a)&&"number"==typeof a.length&&c(a.length)&&!pb(a,"length")});return b}(C("Arguments"),r.Number.isFinite),p=z(B.from)&&B.from||function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(B.prototype.slice),ea=function c(b){b=sb(b)&&p(b)||b;T(b)&&(b=b.reduce(function(b,e){return b.concat(c(e))},[]));return b},J=H.keys,u=function(){},D;D=(D=r.console)&&z(D.warn)&&z(D.log)&&D||{warn:u,log:u};L.as=function(c){var b,d,e,f,g;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),g=f.parentLink,w(g))if(e=g.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"as"))if(q(c=F(c)))if(b=f.trait,f=f.methodName,f!==c)d.recentCalleeName="as",ca(e,b,f,c);else throw new h("Using identical method names in case of aliasing is considered to be a rule violating contradiction.");else throw new h("'as(<String>)' excepts as its sole argument just a 'String' type.");else{c=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().as()'"].join("");if("applyTraits"==b)throw new n([c," in case of aliasing just a certain behavior."].join(""));throw new n(c);}else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return g};L.after=function(c){var b,d,e,f,l,m;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),m=f.parentLink,w(m))if(e=m.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"after"))if(x(c))if(b=m.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=f.trait,b!==c)if(l=f.methodName,f={},c.call(f),g(f[l]))d.recentCalleeName="after",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"afterApply",trait:c,fromTrait:b,methodName:l}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",l,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'after'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'after' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'after' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'after(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().after()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return m};L.before=function(c){var b,d,e,f,l,m;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),m=f.parentLink,w(m))if(e=m.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"before"))if(x(c))if(b=m.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=f.trait,b!==c)if(l=f.methodName,f={},c.call(f),g(f[l]))d.recentCalleeName="before",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"beforeApply",trait:c,fromTrait:b,methodName:l}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",l,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'before'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'before' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'before' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'before(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().before()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return m};L.apply=ha;sa.without=fa;sa.apply=ha;ra.after=function(c){var b,d,e,f;if(w(this))if(e=this.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"after"))if(x(c))if(b=this.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=this.getChild(),f=b.valueOf(),b=f.trait,b!==c)if(f=f.methodName,b={},c.call(b),g(b[f]))d.recentCalleeName="after",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"afterWrap",trait:c,methodName:f}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",f,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'after'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'after' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'after' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'after(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().after()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");return this};ra.before=function(c){var b,d,e,f;if(w(this))if(e=this.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"before"))if(x(c))if(b=this.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=this.getChild(),f=b.valueOf(),b=f.trait,b!==c)if(f=f.methodName,b={},c.call(b),g(b[f]))d.recentCalleeName="before",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"beforeWrap",trait:c,methodName:f}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",f,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'before'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'before' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'before' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'before(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().before()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");return this};A.prototype.execute=function(c,b){var d=this.valueOf();ob[d.type](d,c,b)};return r.Trait={create:function(c){var b,d,e;g(c=F(c))&&(e={chainData:{isTerminated:!1,recentCalleeName:"use"},useTraits:{root:null,rules:[]},applicator:{body:null,proxy:{},root:{},modifiers:[],requires:[],canRequire:!0,didRequire:!1}},b=e.applicator.root,b.requires=cb.bind(e),b.before=Va.bind(e),b.after=Xa.bind(e),b.before.stateful=Wa.bind(e),b.after.stateful=Ya.bind(e),b.afterReturning=Za.bind(e),b.afterThrowing=$a.bind(e),b.afterFinally=ab.bind(e),b.around=bb.bind(e),b=eb.bind(e),d=db.bind(e),c(b,d),e=mb(e));return e},isTrait:qa,isApplicable:x}})(Function("return this")());</script>
```

Comment: That's an amazing answer ! Thanks a lot
Trait seems amazing for big app, why are they not a bit more popular ?
https://github.com/traitsjs/traits.js

Comment: 1/2 @hildericsb >> … why are they not a bit more popular?<< For certain reasons. Type/Object Hierarchies in JavaScript are mostly not that complex.
If they start gaining much more complexity one can refactor, compose and maintain systems by very fine grained (function based) mixin
approaches in order to not run into naming conflicts. On the other hand most human beings by nature tend to use what they are already
familiar with, and JavaScript does not force one into any programming paradigm, concept or pattern except for what the then lean ...

Comment: 2/2 @hildericsb ...  ES3 language core did provide. Thus mostly not carrying the knowledge of what other languages are capable of and/or not feeling pressured enough to ask for new (or switch) perspectives on how to manage JS code bases, it’s not the best launching pad for (even not that) new ideas.

Comment: FYI ... _Trait.js_ as linked by @hildericsb can not do what has been demonstrated by the above example code. The above example sits on [an implementation](https://gist.github.com/petsel/3a598704149e00541db0ff9790146c4a#file-esx-trait-js) of the trait concept which I personally consider [fitting best the languages core features](https://gist.github.com/petsel/8a6aff2d6547b4517e5949e73daca1da#file-esx-trait-md).