# Refactoring legacy mixin-based class hierarchies

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, traits, mixins, composition

I'm currently working on a huge javascript project which has a huge class hierarchy and heavily uses mixins to extend functionality of base classes. Here is an example of how mixin looks like, we're using [compose library](https://github.com/kriszyp/compose) to create class-like objects:

```
// Base.js
var Base = compose({
  setX: function (x) {
    this.x = x;
  },

  setY: function (y) {
    this.y = y;
  },

  setPosition: function (x, y) {
    this.setX(x);
    this.setY(y);
  }
})

// SameXAndY.js - mixin
var SameXAndY = compose({
  // Executes after setX in Base.js
  setX: compose.after(function (x) {
    this.y = x;
  }),

  // Executes after setY in Base.js
  setY: compose.after(function (y) {
    this.x = y;
  }),

  // Overrides setPosition in Base.js
  setPosition: compose.around(function (base) {
    return function (x, y) {
      if (x !== y) {
        throw 'x !== y';
      }
      return base.call(this, x, y);
    }
  })
})
```

We have the following problems with this solution:

- Mixins heavily depend on each other - you can break something by changing mixins' order in base classes.
- There is no easy way to ensure that you can safely include some mixin in your class, you may need to implement additional methods / include additional mixins into it.
- Child classes have hundreds of methods because of the various mixins.
- It's almost impossible to rewrite mixin in Flow or Typescript.

I'm looking for better plugin-like alternatives which allow to gradually refactor all existing mixins with the following requirements:

- Ability to explicitly describe all dependencies (i.e. somehow describe that `PluginA` requires `PluginB` and `PluginC`).
- Plugin should not pollute target class with its methods.
- They should be able to somehow intercept Base class logic (like in `SameXAndY`).
- Plugins should be plain js classes.

I understand that there is no "easy" answer to my question, but I would really love to hear your thought on this topic. Design pattern names, relevant blog posts, or even links to the source code will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Vladimir.

Comment: TypeScript 2.2 has features designed to support mixins.

Comment: @torazaburo yep, I saw this in changelog. However, I still want to get rid of mixins, because of other problem which they cause. Moreover, `compose` library does not support proper js classes, so I still need to rewrite all codebase in order to use ts mixins.

Comment: @pragma ... 1/2 ... promotion alert (kind of) ... If you give this presentation of mine from last weekend a chance of 10 to 15 minutes of careful inspection/read, you might come to the conclusion that the library behind the presentation does cover every single point of your requirements. If it does look promising enough I'm happy discussing this topic from a technical/architectural point of view here ... http://slides.com/petsel/javascript-talents ...

Comment: @pragma ... 2/2 ... the library was written for reasons of research, just fiddling with it in order to discover what traits in JavaScript could/should be like. It was not set up for production code and also is not officially released even though it is stable and would be capable of running your system.

Answer (score 1):

I did refactor the OP's example, and it does what was ask for.
Let me know if I got something wrong.

```js
class BaseXYType {

  constructor(stateValue) { // injected state object.

    this.setX = function setX (x) {
      return (stateValue.x = x);
    };
    this.setY = function setY (y) {
      return (stateValue.y = y);
    };

    Object.defineProperty(this, "x", {
      get: function getX () {
        return stateValue.x;
      },
      enumerable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "y", {
      get: function getY () {
        return stateValue.y;
      },
      enumerable: true
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'valueOf', {
      value: function valueOf () {
        return Object.assign({}, stateValue);
      }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
      value: function toString () {
        return JSON.stringify(stateValue);
      }
    });
  }

  setPosition(x, y) { // prototypal method.
    this.setX(x);
    this.setY(y);
    return this.valueOf();
  }
}


class SameXYType extends BaseXYType {

  // - Traits in JavaScript should be applicable types/objects that are
  //   just containers of trait and object composition rules which
  //   exclusively will be executed at a trait's apply time.

  constructor(stateValue) { // injected state object.
    super(stateValue);

    withSameInternalXAndYState.call(this, stateValue);
  }
}


var withSameInternalXAndYState = Trait.create(function (use, applicator) {

  // local functions in order to enable shared code, thus achieving less memory consumption.
  //
  function afterReturningStateChangeXHandler(returnValue, argsArray, payloadList) {
    var
      stateValue = payloadList[0];

    stateValue.y = argsArray[0];  // same y from x.
  }
  function afterReturningStateChangeYHandler(returnValue, argsArray, payloadList) {
    var
      stateValue = payloadList[0];

    stateValue.x = argsArray[0];  // same x from y.
  }
  function setPositionInterceptor(proceedSetPosition, interceptor, argsArray, payloadList) {
    var
      x = argsArray[0],
      y = argsArray[1];

    if (x !== y) {
      throw (new TypeError([x, "!==", y].join(" ")));
    }
    return proceedSetPosition.call(this, x, y);
  }

  applicator(function sameXAndYBehavior (stateValue) {

    // no additional trait specific behavior within the applicator

  }).requires([

      "setX",
      "setY",
      "setPosition"

  ]).afterReturning(

    "setX", afterReturningStateChangeXHandler

  ).afterReturning(

    "setY", afterReturningStateChangeYHandler

  ).around(

    "setPosition", setPositionInterceptor
  );
});


var
  base_1 = new BaseXYType({ x: 7, y: 11 }),
  base_2 = new BaseXYType({ x: 99, y: 1 }),

  same_1 = new SameXYType({ x: 13, y: 5 }),
  same_2 = new SameXYType({ x: 99, y: 1 });


console.log('("" + base_1) : ', ("" + base_1));
console.log('("" + base_2) : ', ("" + base_2));
console.log('("" + same_1) : ', ("" + same_1));
console.log('("" + same_2) : ', ("" + same_2));

console.log('base_1.valueOf() : ', base_1.valueOf());
console.log('base_2.valueOf() : ', base_2.valueOf());
console.log('same_1.valueOf() : ', same_1.valueOf());
console.log('same_2.valueOf() : ', same_2.valueOf());


console.log('base_1.x : ', base_1.x);
console.log('(base_1.x = "foo") : ', (base_1.x = "foo"));
console.log('base_1.x : ', base_1.x);

console.log('base_1.y : ', base_1.y);
console.log('(base_1.y = "bar") : ', (base_1.y = "bar"));
console.log('base_1.y : ', base_1.y);

console.log('same_2.x : ', same_2.x);
console.log('(same_2.x = "biz") : ', (same_2.x = "biz"));
console.log('same_2.x : ', same_2.x);

console.log('same_2.y : ', same_2.y);
console.log('(same_2.y = "baz") : ', (same_2.y = "baz"));
console.log('same_2.y : ', same_2.y);


console.log('base_1.setY("foo") : ', base_1.setY("foo"));
console.log('base_1.y : ', base_1.y);

console.log('base_2.setX("bar") : ', base_2.setX("bar"));
console.log('base_2.x : ', base_2.x);


console.log('base_1.setPosition("brown", "fox") : ', base_1.setPosition("brown", "fox"));
console.log('("" + base_1) : ', ("" + base_1));

console.log('base_2.setPosition("lazy", "dog") : ', base_2.setPosition("lazy", "dog"));
console.log('("" + base_2) : ', ("" + base_2));


console.log('same_1.setY(543) : ', same_1.setY(543));
console.log('same_1.x : ', same_1.x);
console.log('same_1.y : ', same_1.y);
console.log('same_1.valueOf() : ', same_1.valueOf());

console.log('same_2.setY(79) : ', same_2.setY(79));
console.log('same_2.x : ', same_2.x);
console.log('same_2.y : ', same_2.y);
console.log('same_2.valueOf() : ', same_2.valueOf());


console.log('same_1.setPosition(77, 77) : ', same_1.setPosition(77, 77));
console.log('("" + same_1) : ', ("" + same_1));

console.log('same_2.setPosition(42, 42") : ', same_2.setPosition(42, 42));
console.log('("" + same_2) : ', ("" + same_2));


console.log('same_1.setPosition("apple", "pear") : ', same_1.setPosition("apple", "pear"));
console.log('("" + same_1) : ', ("" + same_1));

console.log('same_1.setPosition("apple", "pear") : ', same_1.setPosition("prune", "prune"));
console.log('("" + same_1) : ', ("" + same_1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>(function(r){function g(a){var c="none",b;Y(a)&&(ta(a)?c=ua:(b=Z(a),t("^class\\s+"+a.name+"\\s+\\{").test(b)?c=va:t("\\([^)]*\\)\\s+=>\\s+\\(").test(b)?c=wa:z(a)&&(c=xa(a)?ya:za(a)||Aa(a)||Ba(a)?Ca:aa)));return c===aa}function C(a){return["^\\[object\\s+",a,"\\]$"].join("")}function v(a,c){var b=Da[c];return!!b&&0<=b.indexOf(a)}function M(a,c,b){return function(){var d=arguments;c.apply(b,d);return a.apply(b,d)}}function N(a,c,b){return function(){var d=arguments,e=a.apply(b,d);c.apply(b,d);return e}}function Ea(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments;c.call(b,e,d);return a.apply(b,e)}}function Fa(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f=a.apply(b,e);c.call(b,e,d);return f}}function Ga(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f=a.apply(b,e);c.call(b,f,e,d);return f}}function Ha(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f;try{f=a.apply(b,e)}catch(l){c.call(b,l,e,d)}return f}}function Ia(a,c,b,d){return function(){var e=arguments,f,g;try{f=a.apply(b,e)}catch(m){g=m}c.call(b,g||f,e,d);return f}}function Ja(a,c,b,d){return function(){return c.call(b,a,c,arguments,d)}}function Ka(a,c){return function(){var b=this[a];g(b)||(b=u);this[a]=M(b,c,this)}}function La(a,c){return function(){var b=this[a];g(b)||(b=u);this[a]=N(b,c,this)}}function Ma(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ea(d,c,this,b)}}function Na(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Fa(d,c,this,b)}}function Oa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ga(d,c,this,b)}}function Pa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ha(d,c,this,b)}}function Qa(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ia(d,c,this,b)}}function Ra(a,c){return function(b){var d=this[a];g(d)||(d=u);this[a]=Ja(d,c,this,b)}}function ba(a,c,b){a.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"without",traitList:c,methodNameList:b}))}function ca(a,c,b,d){a.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"as",trait:c,methodName:b,methodAlias:d}))}function da(a){return ea(p(a)).reduce(function(a,b){q(b)&&a.push(F(b));return a},[])}function fa(){var a,c,b,d,e;if(O(this))if(d=this.valueOf(),e=d.parentLink,w(e))if(b=e.getSetup(),a=b.chainData,c=a.recentCalleeName,v(c,"without"))if(c=da(arguments),1<=c.length)a.recentCalleeName="without",ba(b,d.traitList,c);else throw new h("Not even a single <String> type was passed to 'without' as to be excluded method name.");else{a=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",c,"().without()'"].join("");if("applyBehavior"==c)throw new n([a," in case of excluding one or more certain behaviors."].join(""));throw new n(a);}else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return e}function P(a,c){var b=a.getSetup();if(Sa(c,a.valueOf().traitList))b.chainData.recentCalleeName="applyTraits",b=new Q({traitList:c,parentLink:a}),a.putChild(b);else throw new h("Any trait that got passed to 'apply' needs to be registered before via 'use'.");return b}function Sa(a,c){return a.every(function(a){return 0<=c.indexOf(a)})}function Ta(){var a;a=this.getSetup();var c=this.valueOf().traitList;I(this,a,a.chainData.recentCalleeName);a=P(this,c);return fa.apply(a,arguments)}function Ua(){var a=this.getSetup(),c=this.valueOf().traitList;I(this,a,a.chainData.recentCalleeName);return P(this,c)}function ga(){var a,c,b;b=p(arguments);if(w(this))if(a=this.getSetup(),c=a.chainData,c=c.recentCalleeName,I(this,a,c),a=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",c,"().apply()'"].join(""),v(c,"apply"))if(x(b[0]))if(q(b[1]))if(v(c,"applyBehavior")){c=b[0];b=F(b[1]);a=this.getSetup();var d;if(0<=this.valueOf().traitList.indexOf(c))if(d={},c.call(d),g(d[b]))a.chainData.recentCalleeName="applyBehavior",b=new R({trait:c,methodName:b,parentLink:this}),this.putChild(b);else throw new k(["The requested '",b,"' method has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'apply'."].join(""));else throw new h("Any trait that got passed to 'apply' needs to be registered before via 'use'.");}else throw new n([a," in case of applying just a certain behavior."].join(""));else if(p(b).every(x))if(v(c,"applyTraits"))b=P(this,b);else throw new n([a," in case of applying from one or more traits."].join(""));else throw new h("'apply(\u2026)' excepts either, as its 2nd delimiting argument, just a 'String' type or exclusively one or more 'Trait' and 'Function' types.");else throw new h("'apply(<Trait|Function>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(a);else throw new k("'use(\u2026).apply(\u2026)' only works within a validly chained context, please do not try spoofing the latter.");return b}function ha(){var a;a=this;if(O(a)||G(a))a=a.valueOf(),a=a.parentLink,a=ga.apply(a,arguments);else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return a}function I(a,c,b){var d,e;a&&!c.chainData.isTerminated&&(d=a.getChild())&&(e=d.valueOf())&&("applyTraits"==b&&O(d)?ba(c,e.traitList,[]):"applyBehavior"==b&&G(d)&&(a=e.methodName,ca(c,e.trait,a,a)));c.chainData.recentCalleeName="apply"}function R(a){this.valueOf=function(){return{trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName,parentLink:a.parentLink}};this.toString=function(){return["ApplyLink::singleBehavior :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};return this}function G(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof R||g(a.as)&&g(a.after)&&g(a.before)&&g(a.valueOf)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&x(c.trait)&&q(c.methodName)&&w(c.parentLink))}function Q(a){this.valueOf=function(){return{traitList:a.traitList,parentLink:a.parentLink}};this.toString=function(){return["ApplyLink::fromTraits :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};return this}function O(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof Q||g(a.without)&&g(a.valueOf)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&T(c.traitList)&&w(c.parentLink))}function U(a,c){var b=null;this.getSetup=function(){return c};this.deleteChild=function(){b=null};this.putChild=function(a){b=a};this.getChild=function(){return b};this.valueOf=function(){return{traitList:p(a.traitList)}};this.toString=function(){return["UseRoot :: ",S.stringify(a)].join("")};this.apply=ga.bind(this);this.apply.all=Ua.bind(this);this.apply.all.without=Ta.bind(this);return this}function w(a){var c;return null!=a&&(a instanceof U||g(a.apply)&&g(a.valueOf)&&g(a.getSetup)&&(c=a.valueOf())&&T(c.traitList)&&(c=a.getSetup())&&ia(c))}function Va(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ka(a,c));else throw new h("'before(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'before(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Wa(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ma(a,c));else throw new h("'before.stateful(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'before.stateful(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Xa(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(La(a,c));else throw new h("'after(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'after(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Ya(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Na(a,c));else throw new h("'after.stateful(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'after.stateful(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function Za(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Oa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterReturning(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterReturning(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function $a(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Pa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterThrowing(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterThrowing(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function ab(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Qa(a,c));else throw new h("'afterFinally(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'afterFinally(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function bb(a,c){var b=this.applicator,d=b.root,e=b.modifiers;b.canRequire=!1;if(q(a))if(g(c))e.push(Ra(a,c));else throw new h("'around(\u2026, <Function>)' excepts as its 2nd argument just a 'Function' type.");else throw new h("'around(<String>, \u2026)' excepts as its 1st argument just a 'String' type.");return d}function cb(){var a=this.applicator,c=a.root,b=a.didRequire;if(a.canRequire)if(a.canRequire=!1,a.didRequire=!0,b=da(arguments),1<=b.length)a.requires=b;else throw new h("Not even a single <String> type was passed to 'requires' as method name that a trait, at its apply time, expects to be present at least.");else{if(b)throw new n("'requires' can be invoked exactly once, right after having executed a trait's 'applicator' method.");throw new n("'requires' can not bee invoked after a modifier method, but has to be the direct follower of a trait's 'applicator' method.");}return c}function db(a){I(this.useTraits.root,this,this.chainData.recentCalleeName);this.chainData.isTerminated=!0;var c=this.applicator,b=this.useTraits.rules,d=0>=b.length;if(!d&&!ja(b))throw new k("The trait composition language's rule set does not result in applicable behavior. This happens e.g. if all behavior has been deleted via 'without'.");if(null!=a)if(g(a=F(a)))c.body=a,a.call(c.proxy);else throw new h("The applicator should either stay empty or receive a sole applicable type like a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else d&&0>=c.modifiers.length&&D.warn("The trait descriptor till now did neither receive an applicable function via the 'applicator' method nor any composition rule via 'use(\u2026).apply(\u2026)' nor any method modifier.");return c.root}function eb(){var a;a=ea(p(arguments)).filter(function(a){return x(a)});if(1<=a.length)a=new U({traitList:a},this);else throw new h("Not even a single valid 'Trait' or 'Function' type has been provided to 'use(<Trait|Function>[, \u2026])'.");return this.useTraits.root=a}function y(a,c){return a.findIndex(function(a){return a.trait===c})}function ka(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName}}function la(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,fromTrait:a.fromTrait,methodName:a.methodName}}function A(a){this.valueOf=function(){return fb[a.type](a)}}function ja(a){var c=!0;if(1<=a.length){var b={},c=ma(a),d=na(c);d.forEach(function(a){a.trait.call(a.proxy)});a.forEach(function(a){a.execute(b,d)});c=1<=J(b).length}return c}function gb(a,c,b){var d;if(b[0]!==oa&&(d=c.reduce(function(b,c){g(a[c])||b.push(c);return b},[]),1<=d.length))throw new h("The type misses following required method(s) \u2026 '"+d.join("', '")+"'.");return d}function hb(a,c,b){a.forEach(function(a){a.call(c,b)})}function ib(a){this.call=function(){var c=p(arguments),b;b=c.shift();b=null!=b&&b||null;a.apply(b,c);return b};this.apply=function(c,b){null==b&&(b=[]);c=null!=c&&c||null;a.apply(c,b);return c};return this}function jb(a){this.requires=function(){return p(a)};return this}function kb(a){var c=[],b={};a.call(b,oa);c=J(b).sort(function(a,b){return a<b&&-1||a>b&&1||0});b=null;this.keys=function(){return p(c)};return this}function pa(a,c){this.toString=function(){return"[object Trait]"};this.valueOf=function(){return a};ib.call(this,a);jb.call(this,c);kb.call(this,a);return this}function qa(a){var c;if(c=!!a)(c=a instanceof pa)||(c="object"==typeof a&&g(a.call)&&g(a.apply)&&g(a.valueOf)&&g(a.valueOf()));return c}function x(a){return qa(a)||g(a)}function ma(a){return a.reduce(function(a,b){var c=b.valueOf(),e=c.trait,f=c.fromTrait;e&&0>a.indexOf(e)&&a.push(e);f&&0>a.indexOf(f)&&a.push(f);(c.traitList||[]).forEach(function(b){0>a.indexOf(b)&&a.push(b)});return a},[])}function na(a){return a.map(function(a){return{trait:a,proxy:{}}})}function lb(a,c,b,d){var e=[],f={};if(!(0>=c.length||ja(c)))throw new k("The trait composition language's rule set does not result in applicable behavior. This happens e.g. if all behavior has been deleted via 'without'.");g(b)&&(b.call(f),e=J(f));return[a,c,e,d].some(function(a){return 1<=a.length})}function mb(a){var c,b=a.useTraits.rules,d=a.applicator;a=d.body;var e=d.requires,d=d.modifiers,f=ma(b);lb(f,b,a,d)&&(d=function(a,b,c,d,e){return function(){var f=this,h=p(arguments),l=na(a);l.forEach(function(a){a.trait.apply(a.proxy,h)});b.forEach(function(a){a.execute(f,l)});gb(f,c,h);g(d)&&d.apply(f,h);hb(e,f,h);return f}}(f,b,e,a,d),c=new pa(d,e));return c}var V=r.Function,H=r.Object,B=r.Array,t=r.RegExp,S=r.JSON,h=r.TypeError,k=r.ReferenceError,n=r.SyntaxError,nb=V.prototype,K=H.prototype,ra=U.prototype,sa=Q.prototype,L=R.prototype,oa={},aa="applicable-function",ya="buildin-constructor",va="class-constructor",wa="arrow-function",ua="generator-function",Ca="interface-type",Da={without:["apply","applyTraits"],as:["apply","applyBehavior"],after:["apply","applyBehavior","after","before"],before:["apply","applyBehavior","after","before"],apply:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" "),applyTraits:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" "),applyBehavior:"apply applyBehavior applyTraits without as after before use".split(" ")},fb={beforeWrap:ka,afterWrap:ka,beforeApply:la,afterApply:la,without:function(a){return{type:a.type,traitList:p(a.traitList),methodNameList:p(a.methodNameList)}},as:function(a){return{type:a.type,trait:a.trait,methodName:a.methodName,methodAlias:a.methodAlias}}},ob={beforeWrap:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=b[d];a=a.methodName;c[a]=M((b&&b.proxy||{})[a],c[a],c)},afterWrap:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=b[d];a=a.methodName;c[a]=N((b&&b.proxy||{})[a],c[a],c)},beforeApply:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait),e=y(b,a.fromTrait),d=b[d],e=b[e];b=d&&d.proxy||{};e=e&&e.proxy||{};a=a.methodName;a in c&&delete c.methodName;c[a]=M(b[a],e[a],c)},afterApply:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait),e=y(b,a.fromTrait),d=b[d],e=b[e];b=d&&d.proxy||{};e=e&&e.proxy||{};a=a.methodName;a in c&&delete c.methodName;c[a]=N(b[a],e[a],c)},without:function(a,c,b){var d=a.traitList,e=a.methodNameList.reduce(function(a,b){a[b]=null;return a},{});d.forEach(function(a){a=y(b,a);var d=(a=b[a])&&a.proxy||{};J(d).forEach(function(a){a in e||(a in c&&delete c.methodName,c[a]=function(a,b){return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}(d[a],c))})});a=b=d=e=null},as:function(a,c,b){var d=y(b,a.trait);b=(b=b[d])&&b.proxy||{};d=a.methodAlias;a=a.methodName;d in c&&delete c.methodAlias;c[d]=function(a,b){return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}(b[a],c);a=b=d=b=b=d=a=null}},F=function(a,c){return function(b){return b==c?b:a.call(b).valueOf()}}(K.valueOf,null),E=function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(K.toString),Z=function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(nb.toString),pb=function(a){try{a.call(null,"length"),a=function(a,b){return function(c,e){return c!=b&&a.call(c,e)}}(a,null)}catch(c){a=function(a,c){return function(b,d){var e=b!=c;if(e)try{e=a.call(b,d)}catch(m){e=!0}return e}}(a,null)}return a}(K.propertyIsEnumerable),Y=function(a){return function(c){return typeof c==a}}(typeof V),z=function(a){return function(c){return Y(c)&&typeof c.call==a&&typeof c.apply==a}}(typeof V),qb=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Function")),ia=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Object")),rb=z(H.getPrototypeOf)&&H.getPrototypeOf||function(a){var c=a&&a.__proto__;return c||null===c?c:qb(a.constructor)?a.constructor.prototype:a instanceof H?K:null},W=function(a){return function(c){return(c=t(a).exec(Z(c)))&&c[1]}}("^function\\s+([^(]+)\\("),xa=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(W(c))}}("^(?:Array|ArrayBuffer|AsyncFunction|Atomics|Boolean|DataView|Date|Error|EvalError|Float32Array|Float64Array|Function|Generator|GeneratorFunction|Int16Array|Int32Array|Int8Array|InternalError|Collator|DateTimeFormat|NumberFormat|Iterator|Map|Number|Object|Promise|Proxy|RangeError|ReferenceError|RegExp|Bool16x8|Bool32x4|Bool64x2|Bool8x16|Float32x4|Float64x2|Int16x8|Int32x4|Int8x16|Uint16x8|Uint32x4|Uint8x16|Set|SharedArrayBuffer|StopIteration|String|Symbol|SyntaxError|TypeError|TypedArray|URIError|Uint16Array|Uint32Array|Uint8Array|Uint8ClampedArray|WeakMap|WeakSet)$"),X=function(a,c){var b=t(c);return b.test(W(a))||b.test(W(rb(a)))},za=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:Node|CharacterData|Event|DOMError|DOMException|DOMImplementation|DOMStringList|DOMTokenList|EventTarget|HTMLCollection|MutationObserver|MutationRecord|NodeFilter|NodeIterator|NodeList|Range|TreeWalker|URL|Document)$"),Aa=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:HTMLElement|HTMLMediaElement|Element)$"),Ba=function(a){return function(c){return X(c,a)}}("^(?:CanvasRenderingContext2D|CanvasGradient|CanvasPattern|TextMetrics|ImageData|DOMStringMap|MediaError|HTMLCollection|NodeList)$"),ta=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("GeneratorFunction")),q=function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("String")),T=z(B.isArray)&&B.isArray||function(a){return function(c){return t(a).test(E(c))}}(C("Array")),sb=z(B.isArguments)&&B.isArguments||function(a,c){var b=function(b){return t(a).test(E(b))};b(arguments)||(b=function(a){return ia(a)&&"number"==typeof a.length&&c(a.length)&&!pb(a,"length")});return b}(C("Arguments"),r.Number.isFinite),p=z(B.from)&&B.from||function(a){return function(c){return a.call(c)}}(B.prototype.slice),ea=function c(b){b=sb(b)&&p(b)||b;T(b)&&(b=b.reduce(function(b,e){return b.concat(c(e))},[]));return b},J=H.keys,u=function(){},D;D=(D=r.console)&&z(D.warn)&&z(D.log)&&D||{warn:u,log:u};L.as=function(c){var b,d,e,f,g;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),g=f.parentLink,w(g))if(e=g.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"as"))if(q(c=F(c)))if(b=f.trait,f=f.methodName,f!==c)d.recentCalleeName="as",ca(e,b,f,c);else throw new h("Using identical method names in case of aliasing is considered to be a rule violating contradiction.");else throw new h("'as(<String>)' excepts as its sole argument just a 'String' type.");else{c=["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().as()'"].join("");if("applyTraits"==b)throw new n([c," in case of aliasing just a certain behavior."].join(""));throw new n(c);}else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return g};L.after=function(c){var b,d,e,f,l,m;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),m=f.parentLink,w(m))if(e=m.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"after"))if(x(c))if(b=m.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=f.trait,b!==c)if(l=f.methodName,f={},c.call(f),g(f[l]))d.recentCalleeName="after",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"afterApply",trait:c,fromTrait:b,methodName:l}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",l,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'after'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'after' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'after' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'after(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().after()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return m};L.before=function(c){var b,d,e,f,l,m;if(G(this))if(f=this.valueOf(),m=f.parentLink,w(m))if(e=m.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"before"))if(x(c))if(b=m.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=f.trait,b!==c)if(l=f.methodName,f={},c.call(f),g(f[l]))d.recentCalleeName="before",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"beforeApply",trait:c,fromTrait:b,methodName:l}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",l,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'before'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'before' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'before' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'before(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().before()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'apply'.");return m};L.apply=ha;sa.without=fa;sa.apply=ha;ra.after=function(c){var b,d,e,f;if(w(this))if(e=this.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"after"))if(x(c))if(b=this.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=this.getChild(),f=b.valueOf(),b=f.trait,b!==c)if(f=f.methodName,b={},c.call(b),g(b[f]))d.recentCalleeName="after",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"afterWrap",trait:c,methodName:f}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",f,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'after'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'after' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'after' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'after(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().after()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");return this};ra.before=function(c){var b,d,e,f;if(w(this))if(e=this.getSetup(),d=e.chainData,b=d.recentCalleeName,v(b,"before"))if(x(c))if(b=this.valueOf(),b=b.traitList,0<=b.indexOf(c))if(b=this.getChild(),f=b.valueOf(),b=f.trait,b!==c)if(f=f.methodName,b={},c.call(b),g(b[f]))d.recentCalleeName="before",e.useTraits.rules.push(new A({type:"beforeWrap",trait:c,methodName:f}));else throw new k(["Please consider applying '",f,"' directly. This expected behavior has not been implemented by the trait that got passed to 'before'."].join(""));else throw new k("Passing identical trait references to both 'apply' and 'before' is a contradiction that violates the composition rules.");else throw new h("Any trait passed to 'before' has to be registered before via 'use'.");else throw new h("'before(<Trait|Function>)' excepts as its sole argument explicitly either a 'Trait' or a 'Function' type.");else throw new n(["\u2026 invalid chaining of '",b,"().before()'"].join(""));else throw new k("Please do not spoof the context of 'use'.");return this};A.prototype.execute=function(c,b){var d=this.valueOf();ob[d.type](d,c,b)};return r.Trait={create:function(c){var b,d,e;g(c=F(c))&&(e={chainData:{isTerminated:!1,recentCalleeName:"use"},useTraits:{root:null,rules:[]},applicator:{body:null,proxy:{},root:{},modifiers:[],requires:[],canRequire:!0,didRequire:!1}},b=e.applicator.root,b.requires=cb.bind(e),b.before=Va.bind(e),b.after=Xa.bind(e),b.before.stateful=Wa.bind(e),b.after.stateful=Ya.bind(e),b.afterReturning=Za.bind(e),b.afterThrowing=$a.bind(e),b.afterFinally=ab.bind(e),b.around=bb.bind(e),b=eb.bind(e),d=db.bind(e),c(b,d),e=mb(e));return e},isTrait:qa,isApplicable:x}})(Function("return this")());</script>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a really huge work, thanks a lot! I need some time to familiarize myself with your presentation and underlying concepts, but it looks quite promising.

Comment: @pragma ... you're welcome. And please don't hesitate asking. Real world use cases are exactly what I'm looking for in order to also prove whether JavaScript is in need for trait like composition patterns, like the one used here, or not.

Comment: @pragma ... I'm sorry, I just realized that I always was logged in with google, while serving the provided library from there. Thus not noticing that the provided example then was of no use/help to anyone reading here. I by now did switch the script to another provider making it accessible for everyone and runnable by browsers too (proved for chrome, firefox, safari and msie in case being capable of classes). Have fun, playing with it.

Comment: @pragma ... you might also have a look at another trait based composition code that I meanwhile did refactor in search of examples that could prove this approach ... [Mixins for ES6 classes, transpiled with babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732241/mixins-for-es6-classes-transpiled-with-babel/43129978#43129978)